# A required meta data tag in your android manifest does not exist. App crash at MobileAds.initialize();

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, admob, google-play-services

Getting below issue when trying to initialize admob sdk in my app in application instance. happening when we add,

android:name=".MyApplication" in AndroidManifest.xml <application tag

Exception at, `MobileAds.initialize( this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() { @Override public void onInitializationComplete( @NonNull InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {} });`

Note: No issues found if i initialize the same in activity level.

```
'W/System.err: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesMissingManifestValueException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />'

E/MetadataValueReader: This should never happen.
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: 
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:461)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:450)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.PackageManagerWrapper.getApplicationInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaf.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaf.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:7)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcfz.zzn(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.4.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbei.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.4.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhj.zzw(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.4.0:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhj.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.4.0:8)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.4.0:3)
    at com.example.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:31)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7249)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2168)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8245)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
    2021-10-18 20:10:04.690 27613-27640/com.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1

Process: com.example, PID: 27613
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=27613, uid=11251, (need uid=-1) is not allowed to send as package 
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2389)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2373)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2356)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2298)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getIntentSenderWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6832)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:584)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:567)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:174)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:108)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:86)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2021-10-18 20:10:05.895 27661-27661/? E/weather.servic: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x40000000
2021-10-18 20:10:05.900 27661-27661/? E/weather.servic: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-10-18 20:10:05.910 27661-27661/? E/RefClass: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note that you should never store mutable shared data inside the Application object since that data might disappear or become invalid at any time. Instead, store any mutable shared data using persistence strategies such as files, SharedPreferences or SQLite.**

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class

Should not create singleton instance inside Application class.

Comment: `package="com.example">` this It gives an error because of the package name.
example does not allow it to be used in the package name.`com.kirandani ` try this please.

Comment: i have modified the package name as 'example'. it's not the real one.

Comment: `MobileAds.initialize( this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() { @Override public void onInitializationComplete( @NonNull InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {} });`  where are you invoking this command? MyApplication in ?

Comment: Yes in oncreate of MyApplication class as advised in admob App Open Ads sdk's doc

Comment: I don't know maybe the problem is in MyApplication.class

Answer (score 0):

It gives an error because you didn't add it.
[AdmobQuickStart](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) this link You can get information about detailed installation.

```
     <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
<!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
```

Comment: it's already there bro. but still getting this error.

Comment: If you share the manifest file, I think we can solve the problem.

Comment: this error occurs only if we initialize sdk in application class and refer it in manifest file, but works fine if we do it in activity.